# MS Compute Cluster 2003 Command line - Powershell WMI

Tags: powershell, hpc

I have a compute cluster installation with one headnode and multiple compute nodes. This is shared between multiple environments. I run into issues when there are unattended build upgrades. Robocopy fails complaining about the file being used.

Are there any WMI Classes which I can use to get information about which environment is being used? If that's possible I can stop the process which runs for that particular environment and continue with the upgrade.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Sanjeev

Comment: Sometimes locked files can't be replace but can be renamed. It's not an answer but a work arround.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question right, you are either wanting to get OS build information or File build information.

There are a few very simple WMI queries you can use for this- let's see if this is what you need.

For the OS style query, you will want to do something similar to this:

```
gwmi -class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object *
```

Very handy because you can select all the subs within that query for detailed information.

If you are trying to get the File version of certain files then try this Cmdlet:

```
Get-ItemProperty c:\windows\system32\mshtml.dll | Format-List -property VersionInfo -force
```